# HTTP WebResponse - Read data when it is available in the ResponseStream

Tags: c#, system.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

SO Team,

I have created a Server that sends the JSON string into the TCPClient Stream, This JSON Data will be sent when the user clicks on the Mouse. For Example, for every click of the position System.Windows.Point (x,y) coordinate will be sent to the Client for Processing.

Now Since in this case, the Client does not know when the Data will be sent from Server, Is there an approach to Read-only when the Data is available in the NetworkStream.

Earlier I have worked on a TCP client and server, where the server keeps pushing the data every second, So I created a Timer Event to work with that case.

But in this use-case, I wanted to explore a better solution wherein,
once WebRequest(client) Establishes the Connection with Server, it reads only when the Stream is updated with data. Is there any resources that I can further explore to accomplish this

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: If you want to read out the data asynchronously from a HttpWebRequestStream, you should read directly from the stream. You can use Stream.ReadAsync to read out blocks of data from the stream. You can also wrap the Stream in a `PipeReader`. BUT you need to know that HttpStreams aren't TCP Streams. There is an additional framing layer, and you will likely want to use Chunked encoding...

Comment: @Aron , Thanks !! even if I read asynchronously, How would I know that new data has come in after I have consumed the old one from the stream. At what point do we read data. or Read Async method can do what I need?

Comment: If you use `await Stream.ReadAsync` then the continuation will proceed when new data is available (i.e. "wait until the Read succeeds with more data").

Comment: @Aron Sure, Thanks Aron, I will explore that out